# Reparing grub/boot

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub

I just got my Laptop back from the support center and now I got problems get it back to booting again. Although they did not change anything and the HDD and SDD are still there and the data seems to be as well, it does not work.

When booting, the DELL Logo comes up and the console comes up and shows

```
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

My SDD with Windows 8 and Arch Linux(Antergos) looks like this:

[image: gparted]
(taken from Antergos Live Boot)

So what Ive tried so far is playing with Secure Boot enable/disable, UEFI enable/disable and legacy.

- Booting with all these different settings I get

  error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod' not found.
  Entering rescue mode...
  grub rescue> _

  Entering the boot options I got the usual stuff in Legacy boot (Removable Drive, Hard  drive etc...) and in UEFI Boot I get lots of stuff I installed earlier but actually removed (elementaryOS, Fedora, ubuntu, and two times Windows Boot Manager). Most of these lead to a UEFI Boot screen with an old version of Arch Linux which does not work.

Since I don't have that much knowledge of (U)EFI/SecureBoot/GRUB/GPT/MBR/etc. I don't know what to do. I tried to repair via the boot repair disk, but that one somehow tries to restore elementaryOS instead of arch linux and also gives some kind of error ("Please enable a repository containing the [grub...] packages in the software sources of ArchLinux")

At best I want to be able to boot back into arch linux again but also be able to boot back into windows 8.

Comment: Are you sure the bootdisc order in the BIOS has not been swapped? I.e. do you remember the SDD always to be sdb? If it used to be sda it will not boot and starting it from a rescue disc probably gives you the file not found because grub is looking at the wrong device. I would look at changing that as the first measure.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember if it was sda or sdb or maybe sdc. So the letters correspond to the boot order in BIOS?
I took a look in the BIOS of my laptop but it seems I cannot configure the boot order of the harddrives.

Comment: On older BIOSes you cannot change the boot order. On the other hand there is little change for a drive to get connected on a different cable in a laptop, unless you have the drives in hardware bays that are exchangeable.

Comment: No the HDD and SDD are internal. What else can I do? Can't I just reinstall GRUB or something?

Comment: Yes you can reinstall grub, but you have to make sure that both your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/etc/fstab` are corrected/updated as well.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this, but what would be the best way to reinstall it and update the cfg and fstab?

Comment: the grub stuff can be best done by using chroot e.g. via this [article](http://wiki.archbang.org/index.php?title=Run_grub-install_from_a_live_CD). The fstab setup depends. If it is using UUIDs that you should be fine, if it uses `/dev/sdXn` like paths you should leave them as is, and if they don't work change them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19157/discussion-between-someguy-and-anthon).